# Core Plot Symbol with Custom Path

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-plot

I'm trying to make a custom plot symbol on Core Plot (iOS) using the class method:

```
+(CPPlotSymbol *)customPlotSymbolWithPath:(CGPathRef)aPath
```

I could find limited help on this particular topic, although I have been reading apple docs on creating `CGPathRef` however can't get the custom symbols working. My end target is to create symbols like so:

[image]
[image]

Some of the symbols need to have the red inner circle and some the blue, and some don't have to have the outer circle at all (in which case I am using `ellipsePlotSymbol` without issues).

I am aware I could 'cheat(!)' and just use a background image fill with `rectanglePlotSymbol` or similar but I would really like to do this in code so I don't have to keep creating different images everytime I need a new color etc.

I have made a start but could an expert please complete/help with this! Thank you.

```
// Set up Risk Plot and add to Graph
self.riskValuesPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
self.riskValuesPlot.dataSource = self;
self.riskValuesPlot.identifier = @"Risk Values";
CPTColor *riskPlotColor = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:49.0/255.0 green:82.0/255.0 blue:151.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[graph addPlot:self.riskValuesPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

// Risk Values Line and Point Style
CPTMutableLineStyle *riskLineStyle = [self.riskValuesPlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
riskLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.0f;
self.riskValuesPlot.dataLineStyle = riskLineStyle;

// Trying to draw the outer circle...help required
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0.0f, 0.0f);
CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, 0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f, 0, M_PI * 180, YES);
CPTPlotSymbol *riskSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol customPlotSymbolWithPath:path];
CGPathRelease(path);

// Draw inner circle here
// Set path color then draw circle path with fill?
...

CPTMutableLineStyle *riskSymbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
riskSymbolLineStyle.lineColor = riskPlotColor;
riskSymbol.lineStyle = riskSymbolLineStyle;
riskSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(8.0f, 8.0f);
self.riskValuesPlot.plotSymbol = riskSymbol;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathAddEllipseInRect( path, NULL, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0) );
CGPathAddEllipseInRect( path, NULL, CGRectMake(2.0, 2.0, 6.0, 6.0) );
CGPathAddEllipseInRect( path, NULL, CGRectMake(4.0, 4.0, 2.0, 2.0) );

CPTPlotSymbol *riskSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol customPlotSymbolWithPath:path];
riskSymbol.usesEvenOddClipRule = YES;
CGPathRelease(path);
```

Adjust the sizes of the circles to get the desired relative sizes between the ring and the circle in the middle. A solid color fill is easy and will give you the first sample image. You can use a radial gradient fill to get multiple colors. Set up the gradient so the color transition is hidden by the space between the solid circle and the ring.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I was hoping you would pick this question up. Your answer was perfect. I have the one color symbols working great and will play around with the radial gradient background to get the inner circle a different color. Many thanks and keep up the great work on the framework.